# Storing objects in PHP session

Tags: php, session

The PHP documentation says "You can't use references in session variables as there is no feasible way to restore a reference to another variable."

Does this mean I can't have things like:

```
session_start();
$user = new User;
$user->name = 'blah';
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

I have tried to store a simple string and a User object in session, the string always persists between pages to pages, or after page refresh.  However the User variable is lost in $_SESSION(becomes empty).

any idea?

Edit:
I have confirmed that session_id is the same in all of these pages/subpages,before & after page refresh.

Edit:
Strangely, after I tried serialize and unserialize approach below, the serialized user object(or string) in session still still disappears!

Edit:
finally I figured out what the bug was, looks like somehow $_SESSION['user'] gets overwritten by some mysterious force, if I use any variable other than 'user', then everything's fine.   PHP(at least 5.3 which is the version I'm using) does serialize and unserialize automatically when you put object in the $_SESSION.

```
session_start();
$user = new User();
$user->name = 'blah'
$_SESSION['myuser'] = $user;
```

Comment: PHP sessions can be hijacked, so it's best to never store any user info in them. I'd store a user ID and hashed password in a cookie. Then, when you need the user info, pull from your database (using the ID stored in the cookie) and then validate the password hash. If the hash-check passes, fill your User object with the info from the database.

Comment: but that adds the overhead of database calls every time you need to grab information about the user, instead of retrieving user info once from database, and then be able to use it through the session.

Comment: Sure, it adds overhead. But do you care more about overhead, or security? You *could* store the user data in the session *if* you were to validate it (by coupling the cookie technique). But certainly *don't* use sessions blindly.

Comment: This is worng, is much less secure to save a hash password in a cookie than saving data in your session. The cookie if it's not encrypted can be sniffed and then the attacker has your password (and he can try a rainbow dictionary). Session data is saved in your server (even more you can save it in your DB), the data in your session is secure. An attacker can hijack a session ID not the data inside a session.

Comment: There is an option where you can store the user session in the database instead of a web directory as well when we talk about security

Comment: Why storing the session data in a database would be more secure than storing it in a file? Btw, if the directory where you store your session files is accessible via http (if this is what you're suggesting by calling it a "web directory"), you've got some serious web server misconfiguration!

Comment: @brianreavis: "PHP sessions can be hijacked, so it's best to never store any user info in them." — Actually, it might be safe to do just this, if you have cookies configured correctly: see **session_set_cookie_params()** — and if you also make User a **final** class with **private** member variables and **final public** methods. (The alternative: storing/retrieving temporary session/user data in your database, is quite fiddly, and therefore error prone ⇒ somewhat insecure for that reason.) You need other protections against session hijacking, like HTTPS.

Answer (score 60):

You need to use the [magic __sleep and __wakeup methods](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.sleep) for PHP 5 Objects.

For example in the following code block:

```
$obj = new Object();

$_SESSION['obj'] = serialize($obj);

$obj = unserialize($_SESSION['obj']);
```

__sleep is called by serialize(). A sleep method will return an array of the values from the object that you want to persist.

__wakeup is called by unserialize(). A wakeup method should take the unserialized values and initialize them in them in the object.

Comment: Noah, Don't we have to define __sleep() and __wakeup() in the class, I mean do they reside in the class by default???

Comment: @RajeshPaul I think not, these are magic PHP methods and every class has them, like __construct(), __destruct() and so on, so you don't have to define them again...

Comment: You CAN define them to override the default serialization and deserialization mechanism, for instance to serialize related (referenced) objects along with the main object, and them restoring them all later.

Answer (score 4):

Your code example isn't using references as the documentation was referring to. [This is what php means by references](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.spot.php):

```
$var =& $GLOBALS["var"];
```

As to putting objects into the session, PHP *can* store objects in `$_SESSION`. See http://example.preinheimer.com/sessobj.php.

[What you are seeing is a bug](http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49432) in the order of calls to `__sleep` and `__destruct` (`__destruct` is being called before `__sleep`) and the session module fails to serialize the object at shutdown. This bug was opened on Sep 1, 2009.

Comment: where can I find more examples like the preinheimer car example?! That's simply amazing.

Answer (score 2):

For safe serialization and unserialization encode and decode with base64_encode() and base64_decode() respectively. Below I pass a serialized Object to a session and unserialize it on the other page to regain the variable to an object state.

Page 1

```
<?php

require  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/classes/RegistrationClass.php';
$registrationData= new RegistrationClass();
$registrationData->setUserRegData();
$reg_serlizer = base64_encode(serialize($registrationData));   //serilize the object to create a string representation
$_SESSION['regSession'] = $reg_serlizer;
?>
```

Page 2

```
<?php
session_start();
require  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/classes/RegistrationClass.php';
$reg_unserilizeObj = 
unserialize((base64_decode($_SESSION['regSession'])));
$reg_unserilizeObj->firstName;
?>
```

This article describes issues that may be faced by not doing so.
[issuses with php serialization/unserialization](https://davidwalsh.name/php-serialize-unserialize-issues)

Answer (score 1):

You were right saying you can not store references in sessions variables
assigning an object in PHP 5 and above is doing just that assigning the reference not the obj

That its why you would need to serialize the object (implementing also __sleep in the Class) and assigning the string to a session variable

and deserializing it later (implementing also __wake in the Class) from the session variable later on.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior.  Storing a reference to an object would only work if the memory location for the object didn't change.  In a stateless protocol like HTTP, application state is not persisted between requests.  The next request may be handled on another thread, process, or another server.

Given the inherent stateless nature of a web application, holding a pointer to a memory location is useless.  Therefore the object's state must be broken down into a storage format, saved or transmitted, and then reconstituted when needed.  This process is known as [Serialization](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php).

You can choose to serialize the entire object into session (which maybe dangerous depending on the depth of your object graph, since your object may hold references to other objects and those would need to be serialized as well), or if the object can be reconstituted by querying the database on the next request you may just stash an ID in the session.

[EDIT]

JPot pointed out that objects are automatically serialized to $_SESSION, so explicit serialization isn't necessary.  I'll leave the answer for posterity, but obviously it doesn't help your problem.

Comment: php's session implementation has serialization built-in: it automatically serializes serializable types (includes native types).

Comment: From the PHP docs:  "If you are using sessions and use session_register() to register objects, these objects are serialized automatically at the end of each PHP page, and are unserialized automatically on each of the following pages."  This makes it sound like types are only automatically serialized when registered.  Otherwise, the docs example show objects being explicitly serialized.  Is that inaccurate?

Comment: The docs show objects being explicitly serialized because that page is about how to serialize objects. The blurb about session_register() is only loosely tied to serialization. It's saying basically you don't need to serialize objects explicitly to use them in sessions.

Comment: OK, thanks.  I misread that passage in the docs, appreciate the clarification.