# PHP session for object of class

Tags: php, session

I have problem with session.

```
$kernel = new COM("NETOPENX50.Kernel") or die("Unable to instantiate Netopenx50.Kernel");

$_SESSION['kernel'] = $kernel;
```

its not working :( any idea ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1442177/storing-objects-in-php-session

Comment: You might want to read [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). *It's not working* never is a sufficient description of a problem.

Answer (score 1):

[From the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/faq.com.php#faq.com.q4):

> **Can I store a COM object in a session ?**
>
> No, you can't. COM instances are treated as resources and therefore they are only available in a single script's context.